Calculate disparity for matching feature points
If I have matched a pair of feature points, could I calculate its disparity by simply subtract the u coordinates(uL - uR)? And could use this disparity to calculate the depth for this 3d point?
Because the definition of disparity is the difference between u coordinates, I assume I do not have to recalculate the whole image if I have matched the feature points.
Thank you!
